# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^6}dx=\frac13\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$

Tags: integration

I know that I am meant to use the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ (it was the hint given in the question), however, I don't know how to use it so that I can get the desired result. How can this question be done?

Comment: Substitute $t=x^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, here are the steps
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^6}dx$$
Let $u=x^3$, then $\frac13 du=x^2\ dx$. So now
$$\frac13 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-au^2}du=\frac13 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$